# Using special characters in a string argument to the awk match function. Current locale settings

Tags: character-encoding, awk

I have a problem using the `match` function in `awk` on a string containing special characters. Consider the file `test.awk`:

```
{
    match($0,"(^.*)kon",a);
    print a[1];
}
```

and a corresponding test file "test.txt" with contents "Testing Håkon" (note the norwegian character "å"). The file is encoded in "iso-8859-1" with a length of 14 bytes. The hex dump of the file is given by `xxd -p test.txt` as

```
54657374696e672048e56b6f6e0a
```

From which we can see that the norwegian character "å" has been encoded with the hexadecimal number "e5".. That is, the file is encoded using iso-8859-1 encoding..

Running

```
awk  -f test.awk test.txt
```

Gives nothing at the terminal.. Whereas the correct output should have been "Testing Hå"..

The output of running the `locale` command is:

```
LANG=en_DK.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=en_US:
LC_CTYPE="en_DK.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="en_DK.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="en_DK.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="en_DK.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="en_DK.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="en_DK.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER="en_DK.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="en_DK.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="en_DK.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="en_DK.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="en_DK.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="en_DK.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=
```

which shows that the "LANG" variable is set to utf-8 encoding..

Comment: Edit your question with the results of `set | grep LANG`. Good luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't a problem with `awk` see [here](http://ideone.com/vToLTF). Your `locale` is expecting UTF-8 encoding but your file is using `iso-8859-1` so either set your `locale` to match your file or vice versa.

Note: the second argument of `match()` should be a regexp and the trailing `;` are not required

```
{
    match($0,/(^.*)kon/,a)
    print a[1]
}
```

Comment: Thank you. Yes I see that it is working for you.. But I still can not get it to work.. What do you mean by checking the system `locale`?

Comment: You `locale` isn't the problem!? What version of `awk` are you running and on what platform?

Comment: That's all fine, It must be your input file, check the output of `awk '{ match($0,/(^.*)/,a);print a[1]}' file` and see if the whole line is printed.

Comment: It works if you convert your input file to UTF-8 using "iconv -f ISO-8859-1 -t UTF-8 test.txt > test2.txt"

Comment: What about "LC_ALL=ISO_8859-1 awk -f test.awk test.txt | iconv -f ISO_8859-1 -t UTF-8"?

Comment: The output of `xxd` on the file on my system gives `54657374696e672048c3a56b6f6e0a` that's `c3a5` not `e5`?

Comment: @AxelKemper Can a single file contain mixed utf8 and ascii ?

Comment: You can mix encodings in a single file, but this is obviously not very useful. e5 is the ISO_8859-1 code for å. Awk is expecting UTF-8 if you are using a UTF-8 locale under Ubuntu.

Comment: It seems like awk wants to use utf-8 formatted strings and not iso-8859-1 .. Is there a way to tell awk which encoding to expect?

Comment: Or maybe the problem is the editor I am using ? I use the `Emacs` editor and it seems like it saves files in the `iso-8859-1` format by default.. So it does not respect my `locale` settings (?)..

Answer (score 2):

I've modified your code as:

```
{
    match($0,"(^.*)kon",a);
    print ">>>" a[1] "<<<";
}
```

The result running `GNU Awk 3.1.6` under Windows 7:

```
>>>Hå<<<
```

Under Ubuntu running `GNU Awk 3.1.8` I get:

```
>>><<<
```

To get the desired output, I had to temporarily change the locale settings and translate:

```
LC_ALL=ISO_8859-1 awk -f test.awk test.txt | iconv -f ISO_8859-1 -t UTF-8
```