# How to match non-printable characters?

Tags: regex, awk

I have a file with a different encoding than the machine has. When using regex, `.` does not match non-printable characters for the current character set.

The following prints 0:

```
echo -e "\xfc" | awk '{ print match( $0, "^.*$" ) }'
```

How I can match all chars including non-printable chars?

Comment: On my Ubuntu this: `echo -e "\xfc" | awk '{ print match( $0, "^.*$" ) }'` prints `1`

Comment: On my other Ubuntu this prints `0`, so there may be a local language problem.  (I though I have set the same on both)

Comment: What is the objective?  Do you want to simply determine if the file has non-printable characters or do something else?

Comment: @devnull I want . to match any character just like it should do!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can confirm that it doesn't work with `de_DE.UTF-8` locale, but both `de_DE.iso88591` and `C` print a `1`. I can't tell you why, but the `[:alpha:]` character class matches:

```
echo -e "\xfc" | awk '{ print match( $0, "^([[:alpha:]]|.)*$" ) }'
```

Or maybe you could change the locale settings for that `awk` call:

```
OLDLANG=$LANG; export LANG=de_DE.iso88591; echo -e "\xfc" | awk '{ print match( $0, "^.*$" ) }'; export LANG=$OLDLANG
```

See also [Using special characters in a string argument to the awk match function. Current locale settings](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16760493/2604213).

Comment: himm, i don't know why i haven't accepted this answer till now. Here's your green tick, my fellow friend ;)